# How to access media files in folders with .nomedia

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app that allows users to stream and download music but I want the downloaded music files to be visible only to the app so I create a .nomedia file inside the app download directory but the problem is my app cant fetch the music files in my download folder too.

```
File hidefile = new File(downloadsDir, "SongsFolder/"+".nomedia");
        if (hidefile.exists()) {
            Log.e("FIle", "Exist");
        } else {
            try {
                hidefile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And to fetch songs from my download folder

```
public static ArrayList<MusicFiles> getAllDownloadsAudio(final Context context) {
        final ArrayList<MusicFiles> tempAudioList = new ArrayList<>();
       

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, //For Path
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID
        };

        String folder  = String.valueOf(getDownloadLocation());
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                projection,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
                new String[]{"%"+folder+"%"}, null);



        if (c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                // Create a model object.
                MusicFiles audioModel = new MusicFiles();

                String album = c.getString(0);
                String title = c.getString(1);
                String duration = c.getString(2);
                String path = c.getString(3);
                String artist = c.getString(4);
                String id = c.getString(5);

                // Set data to the model object.
                MusicFiles musicFiles = new MusicFiles(path, title, artist, album, duration, id);
                Log.e("Download Path: "+path, "Album: "+album);
                tempAudioList.add(musicFiles);
                // Add the model object to the list .
               // tempAudioList.add(audioModel);
            }
            c.close();
        }

        // Return the list.
        return tempAudioList;
    }
```

UPDATE
Here is how I download the songs

```
public long downloadMedia(String URL) {
 if (newFile.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Downloading Song", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(URL);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
            request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
            request.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            request.setDescription("Downloding...");
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
            try { //V28 Below
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(String.valueOf(getDownloadLocation()), fileName);//v 28 allow to create and it deprecated method(v28+)
            } catch (Exception e) {
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "SongsFolder/"+ fileName);        }
            downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            Log.i("downloadReference", "" + downloadReference);
        }
 return downloadReference;
    }
```

Comment: What has your problem to do with that file? And what is Android version of used device?

Comment: Who downloaded those files? And why would media store know about author, title, artist and so?

Comment: "I want the downloaded music files to be visible only to the app" -- download the files to `getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()`, rather than a publicly-visible directory. Then, you no longer need `.nomedia`. However, neither that nor your current approach will work with `MediaStore`.

Comment: The files are  .mp3 files which are downloaded using Android download manager to a folder inside downloads.

Comment: My code allows me to download, get song list array and play, I just want to hide the downloaded media. I have update the question plus my download code